# Pure Speed for Lookup Single Value Type c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, linq

.NET 4.5.1

I have a "bunch" of Int16 values that fit in a range from -4 to 32760. The numbers in the range are not consecutive, but they are ordered from -4 to 32760. In other words, the numbers from 16-302 are not in the "bunch", but numbers 303-400 are in there, number 2102 is not there, etc.

What is the all-out fastest way to determine if a particular value (eg 18400) is in the "bunch"? Right now it is in an Int16[] and the Linq Contains method is used to determine if a value is in the array, but if anyone can say why/how a different structure would deliver a single value faster I would appreciate it. Speed is the key for this lookup (the "bunch" is a static property on a static class).

Sample code that works

```
Int16[] someShorts = new[] { (short)4 ,(short) 5 , (short)6};
var isInIt = someShorts.Contains( (short)4 );
```

I am not sure if that is the most performant thing that can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the array sorted? Are the numbers unique, or for example would you have 18400 in there twice?

Comment: What @lc. asked; you seem to suggest they are sorted and unique, but I'm not 100% on it, either.

Comment: @lc there are no duplicate numbers, each one appears in the "bunch" one time. The numbers are in numeric order from smallest (-4) to largest (32760), sorted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you really want [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - just offset the value by 4 so you've got a range of `[0, 32764]` and you should be fine.

That will allocate an array which is effectively 4K in size (32764 / 8), with one bit per value in the array. It will handle finding the relevant element in the array, and applying bit masking. (I don't know whether it uses a `byte[]` internally or something else.)

This is a potentially less compact representation than storing ranges, but the *only* cost involved in getting/setting a bit will be computing an index (basically a shift), getting the relevant bit of memory to the CPU, and then bit masking. It takes 1/8th the size of a `bool[]`, making your CPU cache usage more efficient.

Of course, if this is really a performance bottleneck for you, you should compare both this solution and a `bool[]` approach in your real application - microbenchmarks aren't nearly as important here as how your real app behaves.

Answer (score 3):

Make one bool for each possible value:

```
var isPresentItems = new bool[32760-(-4)+1];
```

Set the corresponding element to `true` if the given item is present in the set. Lookup is easy:

```
var isPresent = isPresentItems[myIndex];
```

Can't be done any faster. The bools will fit into L1 or L2 cache.

I advise against using `BitArray` because it stores multiple values per byte. This means that each access is slower. Bit-arithmetic is required.

And if you want insane speed, don't make LINQ call a delegate once for each item. LINQ is not the first choice for performance-critical code. Many indirections that stall the CPU.

Comment: While bit arithmetic is required for BitArray, it will still consume 1/8th the memory - allowing *other* things to be in the L1/L2 cache as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet a valid point. Which variant is better is not knowable to us. Depends on the rest of the app.

Comment: Indeed - I've expanded on that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to optimize for lookup time, pick a data structure with `O(1)` (constant-time) lookups.  You have several choices since you only care about set membership, and not sorting or ordering.

A `HashSet<Int16>` will give this to you, as will a `BitArray` indexed on `max - min + 1`.  The absolute fastest ad-hoc solution would probably be a simple array indexed on `max - min + 1`, as @usr suggests.  Any of these should be plenty "fast enough".  The `HashSet<Int16>` will probably use the most memory, as the size of the internal hash table is an implementation detail.  `BitArray` would be the most space efficient out of these options.

If you only have a single lookup, then memory should not be a concern, and I suggest first going with a `HashSet<Int16>`.  That solution is easy to reason about and deal with in a bug-free manner, as you don't have to worry about staying within array boundaries; you can simply check `set.Contains(n)`.  This is particularly useful if your value range might change in the future.  You can fall back to one of the other solutions if you *need* to optimize further for speed or performance.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). To find if the value is in it,  it is a  O(1) operation

The code example:

```
HashSet<Int16> evenNumbers = new HashSet<Int16>();

    for (Int16 i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        evenNumbers.Add(i);
    }


    if (evenNumbers.Contains(0))
    {
       /////
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the numbers are sorted, I would loop through the list one time and generate a list of `Range` objects that have a start and end number.  That list would be much smaller than having a list or dictionary of thousands of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If your "bunch" of numbers can be identified as a series of intervals, I suggest you use [Interval Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). An interval tree allows dynamic insertion/deletions and also searching if a an interval intersects any interval in the tree is O(log(n)) where n is the **number of intervals** in the tree. In your case the number of intervals would be way less than the number of ints and the search is much faster.